# My function is taking too long to load

Tags: javascript

I've a function that add text from a text area to a div, but my problem is that it takes a long time to proceed when I add more than 500 lines. It should work in a second when I add 3000 or 4000 lines, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my Add() function:

```
function add(){
    arraySearchTerms = document.getElementById("searchTerms").value.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySearchTerms.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML += '<div style="padding: 6px;border-bottom: #b5aeae; border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;"><span id="term'+ i +'">' + arraySearchTerms[i] + "</span><span style='float: right;'><img src='Red_Cross.png' height='15' width='11'/></span></div>";
    }   
}
```

Thank you for your help.
Edit: Is it the image? It only weights 2k.

Comment: "It should work in a second when I add 3000 or 4000 lines"  Where did you get that impression?  You are doing a DOM operation for every item, and DOM operations are one of the slowest operations you could possibly do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you assign to `innerHTML`, the browser has to clear and re-parse the new HTML string. It's a relatively expensive operation compared to most, especially when there are lots of elements inside. Try coming up with the string first, and only assigning to the element's `innerHTML` at the end:

```
function add(){
  arraySearchTerms = document.getElementById("searchTerms").value.split('\n');
  let newKeywordHtmlStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arraySearchTerms.length; i++) {
    newKeywordHtmlStr += '<div style="padding: 6px;border-bottom: #b5aeae; border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;"><span id="term'+ i +'">' + arraySearchTerms[i] + "</span><span style='float: right;'><img src='Red_Cross.png' height='15' width='11'/></span></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML += newKeywordHtmlStr;
}
```

You should also consider using classes rather than giving each element a long inline `style` attribute, as well as avoiding implicitly creating global variables:

```
function add(){
  const arraySearchTerms = document.getElementById("searchTerms").value.split('\n');
  let newKeywordHtmlStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arraySearchTerms.length; i++) {
    newKeywordHtmlStr += '<div class="keyword"><span id="term'+ i +'">' + arraySearchTerms[i] + "</span><span><img src='Red_Cross.png' height='15' width='11'/></span></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML += newKeywordHtmlStr;
}
```

CSS:

```
.keyword {
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: #b5aeae;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.keyword > span:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
```

As comment notes, if the source of `arraySearchTerms` is untrustworthy and you wish to additionally strip out HTML tags from the `arraySearchTerms` to ensure it doesn't cause any problems, you can call [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) on each item before inserting into the HTML string:

```
newKeywordHtmlStr += '<div class="keyword"><span id="term'+ i +'">' + arraySearchTerms[i].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '') + "</span><span><img src='Red_Cross.png' height='15' width='11'/></span></div>";
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. I should have thought of that.

Comment: -1 for injecting arbitrary data into the context of HTML.  This is a potential security risk and can lead to broken HTML as well by not escaping the text.

Comment: @Brad Why are you blaming the answer for what the questioner is doing? While this is true it should be addressed in a comment to the question. It's silly to expect us to make their code perfect along with answering the question, not to mention it's unnecessary and answers more than what's needed.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Keep in mind that people copy/paste code from Stack Overflow all the time.  The core of this particular question is essentially, "how do I inject a bunch of data into a bunch of HTML and then shove it into a page".  One way to do that, the proper way, is to spin up elements and set their text and other properties before appending to the document.  You'll find that the performance is comparable to the concat-a-bunch-of-HTML-and-crap-together method.  In any case, the concatenated method is fine if the person answering would take 20 seconds and add the appropriate escaping.

Comment: @Brad That's understandable, and yes I'm aware of the correct way to do this. While I agree it's something that should be mentioned in a comment or noted in the answer, going as far as to claim this question isn't useful and giving a -1 seems unnecessary.

Comment: No need to fight guys. I'm just testing the function and I'm not at the stage of thinking about security. I agree that it should be a reflex. Thank you both

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'm also quite happy to remove the downvote if the answer gets fixed.

Comment: @Brad Thanks. For some reason I had been under the impression that thousands of `appendChild`s would be quite expensive compared to inserting one big HTML string all at once (which is why I didn't mention it in the answer), but it's actually not *that* bad. Simple benchmark seems only ~3-6x slower https://jsfiddle.net/bjfxck86/ (warning: will block browser for a bit)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ideally, use a document fragment so that there's only one big chunk appended at the same time.